# "urlShortener is not defined"?

Tags: jquery, html, url-shortener, google-url-shortener, goo.gl

I'm working on using Google's URL Shortener and I keep getting Uncaught Reference Errors. Any ideas how to "define" the function here? Here's what it looks like in the console.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
urlShortener.settings.apiKey='AIzaSyB445qyB-wbJEOgFW73h_HhMc6oYWMBV2b';
```

**^Uncaught ReferenceError: url Shortener is not defined.^**

```
$("#shortIt").click(function()
{
    $("#shortUrlInfo").html("<img src='images/loading.gif'/>");
    var longUrlLink =$("#longUrl").val();
    shortUrl = jQuery.urlShortener({longUrl:longUrlLink});
    $("#shortUrlInfo").html(shortUrl);
});

});
</script>
```

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="google-site-verification" content="aSIpd2NtPwUbwXmpghxvaJfw-2VrgSAFBaxrImdSCT4" />
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="css/remove.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/social-buttons-3.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="http://www.gifmash.co/img/favicon.png" rel="icon" type="image/icon">
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//use.typekit.net/lbp6yxd.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">try{Typekit.load();}catch(e){}</script>
</head>
<body>




<input type="url" id='longUrl' class="form-control" placeholder="">
<input type="button" id="shortIt" class="btn btn-danger" value="Create!"/>



<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.urlshortener.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/getUrlParam.js"></script>
<script src="js/getGif.js"></script>
<script src="js/getVid.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
urlShortener.settings.apiKey='AIzaSyB445qyB-wbJEOgFW73h_HhMc6oYWMBV2c';
$("#shortIt").click(function()
{
    $("#shortUrlInfo").html("<img src='images/loading.gif'/>");
    var longUrlLink =$("#longUrl").val();
    shortUrl = jQuery.urlShortener({longUrl:longUrlLink});
    $("#shortUrlInfo").html(shortUrl);
});

});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

jQuery.urlshortener.js

```
/*!
* jQuery URL Shortener 1.0
* https://github.com/hayageek/jQuery-URL-shortener
*
* Date: 24-Oct-2013
*/
(function ($) {
    var scriptsLoaded = false;
    var clientLoaded = false;

    $.getScript("https://apis.google.com/js/client.js", function () {
        (function checkIfLoaded() {
            if (gapi.client) {
                scriptsLoaded = true;
                gapi.client.setApiKey($.urlShortener.settings.apiKey);
                gapi.client.load('urlshortener', $.urlShortener.settings.version, function () {
                    clientLoaded = true;
                });
            } else window.setTimeout(checkIfLoaded, 10);
        })();
    });


    $.urlShortener = function (options) {

        var settings = {};
        var data = {};
        $.extend(settings, $.urlShortener.settings, options);

        (function checkScriptsAndClientLoaded() {
            if (scriptsLoaded && clientLoaded) {
                if (settings.longUrl != undefined) {
                    longToShort(settings);
                } else if (settings.shortUrl != undefined) //URL info
                {
                    shortUrlInfo(settings);
                }
            } else {
                window.setTimeout(checkScriptsAndClientLoaded, 10);
            }

        })();

        function longToShort(s) {
            var data = {
                'longUrl': s.longUrl
            };
            var request = gapi.client.urlshortener.url.insert({
                'resource': data
            });
            request.execute(function (response) {
                if (response.id != null) {
                    if (s.success) {
                        s.success.call(this, response.id);
                    }
                } else {
                    if (s.error) {
                        s.error.call(this, response.error);
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        function shortUrlInfo(s) {
            var data = {
                'shortUrl': s.shortUrl,
                'projection': s.projection
            };
            var request = gapi.client.urlshortener.url.get(data);
            request.execute(function (response) {
                if (response.longUrl != null) {
                    if (s.success) {
                        if (s.projection == undefined) s.success.call(this, response.longUrl);
                        else s.success.call(this, response);
                    }
                } else {
                    if (s.error) {
                        s.error.call(this, response.error);
                    }
                }

            });

        }

    }
    $.urlShortener.settings = {
        apiKey: 'AIzaSyB445qyB-wbJEOgFW73h_HhMc6oYWMBV2b',
        version: 'v1.0.1',
    };

});
```

Comment: well apparently the javascript you're trying to use isn't in that file or being linked to from that file.  maybe you should add it

Comment: @Deryck I have it linked in the head. <script src="js/jquery.urlshortener.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: paste your whole HTML here

Comment: @Deryck I've updated my question with the urlshortener.js file as well.

Comment: Did you try `$.urlShortener.settings.apiKey` instead of `urlShortener.settings.apiKey` ?

Comment: Oh and PS - you don't even need to do that because your JS file has it at the end already :)

Comment: @Deryck Yeah. Using $ is also the original code from the GitHub link. But when in use I get a different error - `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'settings' of undefined.`

Comment: Inline JS parses before external JS so try either putting it into an external file and then linking it.

Comment: @Deryck edit: For some reason, your comments aren't showing up until I post a following comment.. I'll give that a try right now

Answer (score 0):

You are referring to urlShortener by itself. It isn't a global object.

```
$.urlShortener.settings.apiKey
```

If you say:

```
urlShortener.settings.apiKey = 'floozy';
```

the browser doesn't know what the hell urlShortener is. Because it doesn't exist. Throw that $ in front.

```
$.urlShortener.settings.apiKey = 'floozy';
```

Comment: Should I be using it to reference the urlShortener.js file?

Comment: No, dude. urlShortener is a jQuery plugin. You can't refer to it without putting $ or jQuery in front of it. That's why you have the error. Does that make sense?